# Angular 2 w/ TypeScript: Code Splitting by dynamically Importing Angular modules from a CDN into the core application

Tags: angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading, systemjs

**The Idea:**
I am working on a new architecture pattern for Angular 2, and I seemed to be stuck at an odd point. Lets say I have a core platform with 7 sub Angular modules I want to include into the core. The core being shared services, validation, and etc. The Angular modules need to be separate due to version dependencies by several different clients.

**The Question:** How would one dynamically import the Separate Angular modules into components and modules to be registered on the fly when lazy loading?

**The Goal:**
I want to be able to import or laxy-load components of modules into the application based on version paths; so the core is independent of the features; so the application isn't feature dependent.

**Example CDN:**

Version 1 = https://cdnjs.example.com/v1/featureHome

Version 2 = https://cdnjs.example.com/v2/featureHome

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app',
   template: `
     <div>Loading System Config</div>
      `
 })

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  private constructSystemConfig(){
       //Wrapped in a Promise to get user's versioning of feature
       let version: featureVersions = feature.version;
       let url: string = 'https://cdnjs.example.com/ajax/' + version + '/featureHome.js';
       System.import(url).then(refToLoadedScript => {
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.constructSystemConfig();
  }
}
```

**Idea if Possible:** If one could modify the System.js file on the fly that would be awesome, but I failed at that attempt.

**Another Idea:** https://blog.sstorie.com/providing-external-data-when-bootstrapping-angular-2/

So bootstrapping the application for Angular after I receive an authentication token with a user configuration object response.

```
       System.config({
         transpiler: 'typescript', 
         typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
           map: {
           HomeFeatureBundle: 'https://www.cdnjs.example.com/' + version + '/featureHome';
       },
       packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
     });
```

**My Final Guess would be something like this below:**

```
 // pathEnvironment is a provider informing the environment type 
 // userId is the current loggedIn user's id
 const routes: Routes = [];

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  

 OnInit{
    http.get(pathEnvironment + '/user/id=' + userId)
    .subscribe((data){
      let featureVersion = data.home_bundle.version;
    routes = [{
       path: 'route_name', loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => {
           (require as any).ensure([], require => {
               resolve(require(pathEnvironment + '/' + featureVersion + '/features/homebundle.js').featureHomeModule);
           })
       })
     }]
    }
 }
```